# How do I duplicate a Squarespace portfolio entry and retain the background image?

Tags: background, duplicates, squarespace, sections, portfolio

HELP ME please.

On my Squarespace website I would like to duplicate a portfolio entry and retain the design settings of it. In particular, the background image. The portfolio entry “2050/1” has been setup correctly using code. There is an artwork background that runs behind the portfolio gallery and the footer. When I click ‘duplicate’ in the settings for this entry it creates a new portfolio entry but it has a white background, see “2050/1 (copy)”. Is there a way to duplicate the page, and many more pages, without having to individually add code? Please refer to links attached.

https://www.regardsfromyourfuture.com/future-paintings/project-one-44zcm-57lgb-6glfy-p2f7c-nbdk9-76lc2-zh5z9

https://www.regardsfromyourfuture.com/future-paintings/project-one-44zcm-57lgb-6glfy-p2f7c-nbdk9-76lc2-zh5z9-3pcl8

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS, added via [Custom CSS / CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor) will achieve that.

```
.collection-60b8480265d7df4bcf8f97ed .page-section:first-child .section-background:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transform: scale(100%);
  background-image: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/601a2e3ab7c076212fdf7cc4/1627276381665-TKPRGQK0WMFOD4SMWKS0/Paintings_tall+test.jpg?format=2500w);
}
.collection-60b8480265d7df4bcf8f97ed .page-section:last-child .section-background:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: absolute;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transform: scale(100%);
  background-image: url(https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/601a2e3ab7c076212fdf7cc4/1627276381665-TKPRGQK0WMFOD4SMWKS0/Paintings_tall+test.jpg?format=2500w);
}
```

Note that the URL that is used is the image URL to the image that you uploaded as the background image to the section in the initial post. Instead, you could upload the image via the ["Manage Custom Files" option](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor#:%7E:text=Upload%20files%20(optional)), and then use the URL to that image instead.

Comment: Hi @Brandon

Thanks for your response. The code has worked and transferred the background image to all entries. However, behind the portfolio image there is still a colour. See links below. Are you able to make them transparent too?

Does it matter if I leave the image URL as is or is it better to switch to the Manage Custom Files option?

Thanks :)

https://www.regardsfromyourfuture.com/future-paintings/project-one-44zcm-57lgb-6glfy-p2f7c-nbdk9-76lc2-zh5z9-3pcl8

https://www.regardsfromyourfuture.com/future-paintings/project-one-44zcm-57lgb-6glfy-p2f7c